External monitor does not work with newer kernel
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my ThinkPad P16, with the following nvidia drivers installed: nvidia-driver-545 (proprietary), which is working stable.
I have two kernel versions installed:

6.8.0-49-generic
6.8.0-18-generic

External desktops work with 6.8.0-18-generic without any problem. However, when switching to 6.8.0-49-generic, neither of my two external desktops is recognized anymore.
Any idea why it's not working with a newer kernel version?

I remember from reading other questions that 6.8.0-49-generic kernel has a bug in it, so boot from a different kernel instead, and wait for a kernel update to fix the bug.
